# Waiting for redux state to meet condition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, promise, race-condition

I have the following function, which is meant to allow me to wait for a particular condition to obtain in my redux state.

```
async function when(store, condition) {
    if (condition(store.getState())) {
        return;
    } else {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
                if (condition(store.getState())) {
                    unsubscribe();
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

However, I'm struggling to work out if this is free of race conditions. In particular, if I have a function like...:

```
async function foo(store) {
    await when(store, thereAreExactlyThreeTodoItems);

    doSomethingThatRequiresExactlyThreeTodoItems();
}
```

...am I guaranteed that the condition represented by `thereAreExactlyThreeTodoItems()` is `true` when `doSomethingThatRequiresExactlyThreeTodoItems()` is called? Or does this need a further step to guarantee? i.e.:

```
async function foo(store) {
    do {
        await when(store, thereAreExactlyThreeTodoItems);
    } while (!thereAreExactlyThreeTodoItems(store.getState());

    doSomethingThatRequiresExactlyThreeTodoItems();
}
```

The worry I have in mind is: could an action be dispatched that invalidates the condition after `resolve()` is called, but before control is returned to `foo()`? Unfortunately, I don't have quite a good enough mental model of the javascript event loop to be sure.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Very interesting. When resolve() gets called, it queues the promise callback on the microtask queue. Items on the microtask queue are only scheduled to be executed by the event loop when the current call stack is empty. If it so happens that resolve() gets called while an action is being dispatched, the event loop will first run the dispatch to completion (which means the condition can no longer be guaranteed to be true) and then start picking up the promise callbacks from the microtask queue. So you'll need additional steps to ensure a guarantee. I'm not sure what those steps are though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good what you are trying to do, the only thing which seems strange is that you do not cache the promise creation...

I think you have to create a map and cache the created promises so you do not create a new promise for the same functions.

In this case, I don't see a way in which you can have race conditions problems.

Something along this lines:

```
const cache = {}

function when(store, condition, id) {
    if (condition(store.getState())) {
        return;
    } else if(!cache[id]) {
           cache[id] = true;
           return new Promise(resolve => {
                const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
                if (condition(store.getState())) {
                    unsubscribe();
                    resolve();
                    delete cache[id]
                }
            });
          });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's happening with the caching there. Your description says you are caching the promise, but your code looks like its caching the value `true`.

Comment: it caches the value true of the specific function call id, so if it comes next time the same function it will not recreate the promise again. It's a simple cache system.